# npm : Postinstall not running in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I have a npm package (npm v 5.5.1 and node version is 9.2.0). If i run `npm install` on local machine then the `postinstall` defined in package.json is executed but if I run the same command `RUN npm install` in a Docker file i.e. when the command is run inside the container then the `postinstall` step is not executed. Any inputs what could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try running install with `--unsafe-perm` option. When running as root, npm won't run any scripts.

Alternatively, create a user in the Dockerfile and switch to that user:

```
FROM ...
RUN groupadd -r app && useradd -r -g app app
USER app
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option to the selected answer (@yamenk's), tested on <v9.x which includes the OP's version:
You could add this line to your dockerfile to configure your npm config inside the container (thus, allowing the execution of the postinstall script with the necessary permissions):

```
FROM ...
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

If on v9:

```
FROM ...

# Create a non-root user
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false appuser

# Set the working directory (optional, uncomment if needed)
# WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies as the non-root user, this will run postinstall
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app \
  && npm install

# BONUS: you can go back to default user w/ USER root instead, but if you want to run the application, you should do it as the non-root user, as in: USER appuser
```

Comment: unsafe-perm is removed from npm https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/2196
is there any other option to resolve the problem?

Comment: @Sheldeeb it is not a flag but a config tweak in my answer, as opposed to the selected answer (the flag was removed indeed, not the config) you can optionally create a `.npmrc` file, add it & set it to `unsafe-perm=true`

Comment: even the config is removed, try to set it in npm v9

Comment: @Sheldeeb ah you're using v9, my response addresses OP's question version (v5), breaking changes were stated on v7 although it works until v8 (even if the docs don't mention it), on v9 no config is used indeed, in that case the uid and gid of the working directory owner are taken if npm is ran on root, so then, yes you should create a user that has enough permissions, switch to it and run install. I'll update my answer step by step.

Comment: nice, but there is another issue. this answer is not cross-platform

Comment: @Sheldeeb sure, but you should open a new question addressing all your requirements (as OP's needs are already covered for this specific case, which mentions versions) so we can help, or better yet, post a new answer containing your remarks, here I'm just assuming alpine version image for Docker, which is the most common case.