# Bumping package.json version without invalidating docker cache

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm using a pretty standard Dockerfile to containerize a Node.js application:

```
# Simplified version
FROM node:alpine

# Copy package.json first for docker build's layer caching
COPY package.json package-lock.json foo/
RUN npm install

COPY src/ foo/
RUN npm run build
```

Breaking up my `COPY` into two parts was advantageous because it allowed Docker to cache the (long) `npm install` step.

Recently, however, I started bumping my `package.json` version using semver. This had the side effect of invalidating the Docker cache for the `npm install` step, lengthening my build times significantly.

Is there an alternative caching strategy I can use so that `npm install` only runs when my dependencies change?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's my take on this, based off other answers, but shorter and with usage of `jq`:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM endeveit/docker-jq AS deps

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487433
# To prevent cache invalidation from changes in fields other than dependencies

COPY package.json /tmp

RUN jq '{ dependencies, devDependencies }' < /tmp/package.json > /tmp/deps.json

FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /tmp/deps.json ./package.json
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm ci
# https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html#description

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

LABEL maintainer="Alexey Vishnyakov <n3tn0de@gmail.com>"
```

I extract `dependencies` and `devDependencies` fields to a separate file, then on next build step I copy it from the previous step as `package.json` (`COPY --from=deps /tmp/deps.json ./package.json`).

After `RUN npm ci`, `COPY . .` will overwrite gutted `package.json` with the original one (you can test it by adding `RUN cat package.json` after `COPY . .` command.

Note that [npm-scripts commands](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) like `postinstall` won't run since they're not present in the file during `npm ci` and also if `npm ci` [is running from `root`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748075/npm-postinstall-not-running-in-docker) and without `--unsafe-perm`

Either run commands after `COPY . .` or/and (if needed) include them via `jq` (changing command will invalidate cache layer) or add `--unsafe-perm`

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM endeveit/docker-jq AS deps

COPY package.json /tmp

RUN jq '{ dependencies, devDependencies, peerDependencies, scripts: (.scripts | { postinstall }) }' < /tmp/package.json > /tmp/deps.json
# keep postinstall script 

FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /tmp/deps.json ./package.json
COPY package-lock.json .

# RUN npm ci --unsafe-perm 
# allow postinstall to run from root (security risk)

RUN npm ci
# https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html#description

RUN npm run postinstall

...
```

Comment: I tested this, using `node:12-alpine` for both containers, and `apk add jq` into the `deps` version.  Works great.  I think there is a bit of an overhead in having two containers in the build process, but not as much as having to install deps on every build.

Comment: @n3tn0de Is there a reason you don't copy `package-lock.json` from `deps`?

Comment: Oh, I see. `deps` does not change `package-lock.json`. This raises the question when `package-lock.json` changes or is expected to change. I expect that you use VCS like Git to track `package-lock.json` and that the `package-lock.json` is in sync with `package.json` in the VCS, i.e. the `version` field is the same in both files and the dependencies in `package-lock.json` are based on the dependencies specified in `package.json`. Since the version in `package-lock.json` is changed, the layer `RUN npm i` is not cached.

Comment: @maiermic Yes, I am tracking the `package-lock.json` and it's always is in sync with `package.json`.  
And also yes, if either package.json or package-lock.json are updated, Docker layer (cache) will be invalidated and trigger fresh `npm i`/`npm ci`

Comment: * either **deps** fields (or any other specified in jq) in  `package.json` or `package-lock.json` (in any part) are updated, Docker layer (cache) will be invalidated

Answer (score 9):

You can add an additional "preparation" step in your Dockerfile that creates a temporary `package.json` where the `"version"` field is fixed. This file is then used while installing dependencies and afterwards replaced by the "real" `package.json`.
As all of this happens during the Docker build process, your actual source repository is not touched (so you can use the environment variable `npm_package_version` both during your build and when running the docker script, e.g. to tag) and the solution is portable:

**Dockerfile:**

```
# PREPARATION
FROM node:lts-alpine as preparation
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
# Create temporary package.json where version is set to 0.0.0
# – this way the cache of the build step won't be invalidated
# if only the version changed.
RUN ["node", "-e", "\
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf-8'));\
const pkgLock = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package-lock.json', 'utf-8'));\
fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify({ ...pkg, version: '0.0.0' }));\
fs.writeFileSync('package-lock.json', JSON.stringify({ ...pkgLock, version: '0.0.0' }));\
"]

# BUILD
FROM node:lts-alpine as build
# Install deps, using temporary package.json from preparation step
COPY --from=preparation package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
# Copy source files (including "real" package.json) and build app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

If you think inlining the Node script is iffy (I like it, because this way the entire Docker build process can be found in the Dockerfile), you can of course extract it to a separate JS file:

**create-tmp-pkg.js:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf-8'));
const pkgLock = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package-lock.json', 'utf-8'));

fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify({ ...pkg, version: '0.0.0' }));
fs.writeFileSync('package-lock.json', JSON.stringify({ ...pkgLock, version: '0.0.0' }));
```

and change your preparation step to:

```
# PREPARATION
FROM node:lts-alpine as preparation
COPY package.json package-lock.json create-tmp-pkg.js ./
# Create temporary package.json where version is set to "0.0.0"
# – this way the cache of the build step won't be invalidated
# if only the version changed.
RUN node create-tmp-pkg.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I spent some time thinking about this. Fundamentally, I'm cheating because the `package.json` file is, in fact, changed, which means anything that circumvents the cache invalidation technically makes the build not reproducible.

For my purposes, however, I care more about build time than strict cache correctness. Here's what I came up with:

**build-artifacts.js**

```
/*
Used to keep docker cache fresh despite package.json version bumps.

In this script
- copy package.json to package-artifact.json
- zero package.json version

In Docker
- copy package.json
- run npm install normal
- copy package-artifact.json to package.json (undo-build-artifacts.js accomplishes this with a conditional check that package-artifact exists)
*/

const fs = require('fs');
const package = fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync('package-artifact.json', package);
const modifiedPackage = { ...JSON.parse(package), version: '0.0.0' };
fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(modifiedPackage));

const packageLock = fs.readFileSync('package-lock.json', 'utf8');
fs.writeFileSync('package-lock-artifact.json', packageLock);
const modifiedPackageLock = { ...JSON.parse(packageLock), version: '0.0.0' };
fs.writeFileSync('package-lock.json', JSON.stringify(modifiedPackageLock));
```

**undo-build-artifacts.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

const hasBuildArtifacts = fs.existsSync('package-artifact.json');
if (hasBuildArtifacts) {
  const package = fs.readFileSync('package-artifact.json', 'utf8');
  const packageLock = fs.readFileSync('package-lock-artifact.json', 'utf8');

  fs.writeFileSync('package.json', package);
  fs.writeFileSync('package-lock.json', packageLock);

  fs.unlinkSync('package-artifact.json');
  fs.unlinkSync('package-lock-artifact.json');
}
```

These two files serve to relocate `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, replacing them with artifacts that have zeroed-out versions. These artifacts will be used in the docker build, and will be replaced with the original versions upon `npm install` completion.

I run `build-artifacts.js` in a Travis CI `before_script`, and `undo-build-artifacts.js` in the Dockerfile itself (after I `npm install`). `undo-build-artifacts.js` incorporates a check for the build artifacts, meaning the Docker container can still build if `build-artifacts.js` hasn't run. That keeps the container portable enough in my books. :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, because I was using npm scripts to start and tag the docker build (`docker image build . -t imageName:$npm_package_version`) but the version kept showing up as `0.0.0` – because in order for this to work you need to change the version before starting the build.  

I added [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487433/8571642) where the entire `package.json` transformation happens *within* Docker, feel free to check it out :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on n3tn0de [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59606373/3746664)
I changed the Dockerfile to be

```
######## Preperation
FROM node:12-alpine AS deps

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm version --allow-same-version 1.0.0


######## Building
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This approach will avoid using 2 different Docker images -less download and less storage- and fix/avoid any issues in package.json

Comment: This is great. It's way better to use existing `npm` functionality (that updates both package.json and package-lock.json) instead of having to write a custom script. You could also add the `--no-commit-hooks --no-git-tag-version` flags to `npm version` so that it doesn't rely on git at all.

Comment: @MRashad Why is the preperation stage needed? Why not just have one stage and put the `RUN npm version...` before the `RUN npm ci` line? Wouldn't that ensure it's cached until that point, then the `COPY . .` would put the correct `package*.json` files in place

Comment: @AndyMadge
Docker uses each layer to build the next layer, if all the steps were in the same stage then the layer of `RUN npm version --allow-same-version 1.0.0` will have a different hash because the previous one is different.
But in the current approach, In `Building` all the layers before the `COPY . .` step will always be the same unless you changed the dependencies

Comment: @MRashad yep I see what you mean - when version bumping, the `package*.json` files will _always_ have been modify and would invalidate the cache for the Prep stage, but this trick keeps the cache valid for the Building stage.

Answer (score 3):

I went about this a bit different. I just ignore the version in `package.json` and leave it set to 1.0.0. Instead I add a file `version.json` then I use a script like the one below for deploying.

**This approach won't work if you need to publish to npm, since the version will never change**

version.json

```js
{"version":"1.2.3"}
```

deploy.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
VERSION=`node -p "require('./version.json').version"`

#docker build
docker pull node:10
docker build . -t mycompany/myapp:v$VERSION

#commit version tag
git add version.json
git commit  -m "version $VERSION"
git tag v$VERSION
git push origin
git push origin v$VERSION

#push Docker image to repo
docker push mycompany/myapp:v$VERSION
```

I normally just update the version file manually but if you want something that works like `npm version` you can use a script like this that uses the semvar package.

patch.js

```js
var semver = require('semver')
var fs = require('fs')
var version = require('./version.json').version
var patch = semver.inc(version, 'patch')

fs.writeFile('./version.json', JSON.stringify({'version': patch}), (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    console.log(version + ' -> ' + patch)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Patching the version can be done without jq, using basic sed:

```
FROM alpine AS temp
COPY package.json /tmp
RUN sed -e 's/"version": "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+",/"version": "0.0.0",/'  
  < /tmp/package.json > /tmp/package-v0.json

FROM node:14.5.0-alpine
....
COPY --from=temp /tmp/package-v0.json package.json
...
```

The sed regex assumes that the version value follows the semver scheme (e.g. 1.23.456)

The other assumption is that the `"version": "xx.xx.xx`," string is not found elsewhere in the file. The "," at the end of the pattern can help to lower the probability of "false positives". Check it before with your `package.json` file by security of course.

Answer (score 1):

Another option [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) now has `pnpm fetch` which only uses the lockfile so you are free to make other changes to `package.json`

This requires switching from npm/yarn to using pnpm

Example from: https://pnpm.io/cli/fetch

```
FROM node:14

RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm

# pnpm fetch does require only lockfile
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN pnpm fetch --prod


ADD . ./
RUN pnpm install -r --offline --prod


EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. remove version from package json
2. install packages for production
3. Copy to production image

Benefits:

- Can freely patch package json without invalidating docker
- If dependencies were not changed will not do unecessary npm install for production (packages don't change that frequently)

in practice:

```
# prepare package
FROM node:14-alpine AS package
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
RUN node -e "['./package.json','./package-lock.json'].forEach(n => {  \
            let p = require(n);                               \
            p.version = '0.0.0';                              \
            fs.writeFileSync(n, JSON.stringify(p));           \
          });"

# install deps
FROM node:14-alpine AS build
COPY --from=package package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production

# production
FROM node:14-alpine
...
COPY . .
COPY --from=build ./node_modules ./node_modules
...
```