# Docker-Compose fail

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm working with docker, docker-compose, trying to create an image but I'm getting an issue that I can't fix, I have tried a lot of ways but nothing seems to work, this configuration for my image, this is my docker file

```
FROM node:16-alpine@sha256:53ebfa5e6df1e458b47f677cb4f6fd3cf1d079083647dc40d182910a57b5a63d
RUN apk add dumb-init
ENV PORT=443
ENV NODE_ENV=development
ENV DBUSER=user
ENV DBPASS=pass
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=node:node . /app
RUN npm ci --only=prod
USER node
CMD ["dumb-init", "node", "/app/index.js"]
```

And my docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '1.7'
services:
 web:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.web
   ports:
    - "9000:443"
  extra_hosts:
    "host.docker.internal": host-gateway
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
Dockerfile*
install.sh
README.md
docs/
dev/
var/db/
var/db.tar.gz
node_modules
npm-debug.log
.dockerignore
.git
.gitignore
.npmrc
```

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "@peculiar/webcrypto": "^1.1.7",
  "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "fs": "0.0.1-security",
  "fs.promises": "^0.1.2",
  "https": "^1.0.0",
  "rethinkdb": "^2.4.2",
  "uuid": "^8.3.2",
  "ws": "^8.2.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^8.8.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
  "husky": "^7.0.4",
  "lint-staged": "^12.3.3",
  "prettier": "^2.5.1"
},
```

And this is the error that I'm getting when I run *docker-compose build*:
[image]

Comment: It says `install.sh` cannot be found. Does that file exist? Does it get included in the `COPY`? Do you have a `.dockerignore` file? You probably don't want to copy over `node_modules`

Comment: This looks like a problem with one of your NPM dependencies. Can you add your `package.json` to the question?

Comment: @Phil yes, that files `install.sh` does exist and this is my `.dockerignore` file https://pasteboard.co/5SPcrEnTDMy0.png

Comment: @MosheKatz this is my `package.json` dependencies https://pasteboard.co/UNdmzYaB97L6.png

Comment: So your `.dockerignore` files lists `install.sh`? If so, it should be pretty clear why this isn't working

Comment: @Phil done, added extra information to the question.

Comment: Your dockerignore file has install.sh in it which means that it does not get copied over by the COPY command

Comment: I already try to remove `install.sh` from the dockerignore file and same result

Comment: You'd need to run `docker compose build` (or `docker compose up --build`) to rebuild the image with your `install.sh` file included

Comment: Tried that @Phil and did not work, is weird because first time I run the command for build worked fine, since then I just installed dev dependencies like eslint, prettier.

Comment: I fix the issue following this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110793/bumping-package-json-version-without-invalidating-docker-cache) because that install.sh file was not part of the setup (confirmed by creator) of docker but was needed for other situations, so I tried to cache dependencies and worked fine, thanks guys!